# Not able to subscribe to Reports? Keeps giving error!

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, reporting, permissions, profile

I am getting following error when trying to subscribe to reports -
"**We couldn't set up your subscription. Try subscribing again. If you still can't subscribe, ask your Salesforce admin for help.**"

I am doing the Lightning Experience Reports & Dashboards Specialist superbadge.

[image]

I checked/unchecked many reports related permissions on Profile, but it keeps giving this error.

I am not able to find why is this happening & its really frustrating as its the last step to complete the Superbadge. 
Please help.

Comment: can you try doing same in classic?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Tried that too....Wont work

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Found solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a solution to this weird problem.

I was not able to subscribe because storage limit was exceeded in my Developer Org.

Max limit is 5.0 MB and in my Org it was showing 6.2 MB.
So i deleted around 1000 records to bring size below 5.0 MB.

You can find it under Setup > Storage Usage.

And then I was able to subscribe Reports again.

Got to learn something new..!!

Comment: I doubt anyone would face something like this. The more you know.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I found online that many people are facing this issue....Even some have raised case against it.

Comment: This totally makes sense technically, but the error is definitely misleading. If possible, I'd consider logging a bug with support.